# Javascript code to add REL attribute and append CLASS attribute

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm looking for some Javascript code that will add a REL attribute into the A link element, and then append a CLASS attribute into the Button element within it.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="column-main">
Sample Text Here
</td>
<td class="column-url">
<a href="website.com"><button class="classNamehere">View</button></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'd like the target the A link and Button element within it in order to change it to:

```
<a href="website.com" rel="iLightbox" ><button class="classNamehere fusion-lightbox-link">View</button></a>
```

This is what I've tried...

```
$('.column-url a').attr( 'rel', 'iLightbox' );
$('.column-url button').attr( 'class', 'fusion-lightbox-link' );
```

Comment: Hi @IronSea could you provide some of your own javascript code even code that does not work? While we are happy to help, users like myself are not usually inclined to do all the work for you.

Comment: @IronSea I personally disagree with MichaelSorensen and think that if people knew how to do things themselves they wouldn't ask questions. I'm typing up an answer for you now :)

Answer (score 1):

These are three examples that works differently to achieve what you want:

```
    // This code would be the code working for your example, only get one element and apply the new attribute and class to id 
    var tableTd = window.getElementsByClassName('column-url')[0],
        aLink = tableTd.getElementsbyTagName('a')[0],
        aButton = aLink.getElementsbyTagName('button')[0];

        aLink.setAttribute('rel', 'iLightbox');
        aButton.classList.add('fusion-lightbox-link');

    // This would work if you have the link and button inside a specific container (td for example)
    var container = window.getElementsByClassName('column-url');

    for( var i = 0; i < tableTd.length, i++)[
        container[i].getElementsbyTagName('a')[0].setAttribute('rel', 'iLightbox');
        container[i].getElementsbyTagName('a')[0].getElementsbyTagName('button')[0].classList.add('fusion-lightbox-link');
    }

    // This would look for all A tags with specific class name and set rel attribute to id, then find the button and add a class to it
    var aLinks = window.getElementsByClassName('aClassName');
    for( var i = 0; i < aLinks.length, i++)[
        aLinks[i].setAttribute('rel', 'iLightbox');
        aLinks[i].getElementsbyTagName('button')[0].classList.add('fusion-lightbox-link');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Step 1. Get a reference

In order to edit an element, you first need a way to specify ***which*** element you want to edit. In programmer speak this is known as getting a *reference* to an element. There are several ways to do this in JavaScript. One of the most common is using `document.getElementById()` and assigning the element a unique ID. For instance, if you modified your HTML like so:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="column-main">
Sample Text Here
</td>
<td class="column-url">
<a id="my-link" href="website.com"><button class="classNamehere">View</button></a>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Then you could get a reference to your `<a>` tag by using the following code:

```
var myLink = document.getElementById("my-link");
```

If you do not have the ability to edit the HTML, there are still some options available to you. For instance, you can use `document.getElementsByTagName()` to return an array of all elements using a certain tag. In this way you could select the `<table>` and look for the `<a>` tag within it:

```
var myLink = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].children[0].children[0].children[1];
```

Note that this makes a few assumptions about the structure of your page:

- I grabbed the 0th (first) element with a tag of `table`. This assumes that there are no other tables on your page before this one
- I grabbed the 0th (first) child of the table element. This assumes that the first element is going to be a `tbody`
- I grabbed the 0th (first) child of the tbody element. This assumes that the first row contains the link you want to modify
- I grabbed the 1st (second) child of the row. This assumes that the link will be in the second column

If these assumptions don't hold, you may need more complex logic to locate your link

### Step 2. Edit an element

Once you have a reference to your element, it's deceptively simple to change ***most*** attributes. To edit the `rel` attribute, you just do this:

```
myLink.rel = "iLightbox";
```

That's it!

### Step 3. Adding classes

Modifying classes is slightly more complex. Because what's displayed in HTML as a space-separated list of classes is actually in memory an array of different single-word classes. In other words:

```
<button class="a b c d">
```

Is understood by the computer to be:

```
Button:
    Class 1: "a"
    Class 2: "b"
    Class 3: "c"
    Class 4: "d"
```

If you wanted to remove a single class (say, `c`) then instead of setting the class to `"a b d"` (which requires you to know what ***other*** classes the element had), you can just say `element.classList.remove("c")` -- this will remove that class but leave the others unaffected.

So in order to add a class to your button, we will first get a reference to it (using the link as a starting point) and then use the appropriate API to modify it:

```
var myButton = myLink.children[0];
myButton.classList.add("fusion-lightbox-link");
```

Again, notice the assumption: I assumed that the button is the first child of the link

### Alternative: Working backwards

Instead of trying to find the link first and then the button, if you have a custom class on the button you can start with that and go up using `parentNode` instead of `children`:

```
var myButton = document.getElementsByClassName("classNameHere")[0];
myButton.classList.add("fusion-lightbox-link");
var myLink = myButton.parentNode;
myLink.rel = "iLightbox";
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response, Steven! It looks like the "Working Backwards" approach may be the right fit for what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to target all of the A link elements that contain the Button element with the "classNameHere" class attribute. If I wanted to target all matching instances, would I use the code without the [0] index element?